# Uniform c.r.v and volume of slice (probability). two variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity, random-variables

I have this homework I'm struggling with.

Given Uniform
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{4} ,  \  -1\leq x\leq   1, \  -1\leq y\leq   1 \\ 0, \ \textrm{otherwise}  \\ \end{cases}$$

I need to find the probability of
$$ \mathbb{P}(X^{2}+Y^{2} \leq 1) $$

this what I'm thinking

The volume of this slice of a sphere with centrum (0,0,0) and r= 1 is the probability.

Is this assumption correct and if so how do I find the volume?
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obgWw.png)

Comment: how did you get a sphere

Comment: the slice of the sphere has an height of 1/4. I couldnt think of other ways to calculate the probability

Comment: In general, one has that for $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\mathbb{P}\big((X,Y) \in A\big) =\iint_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)~dx~dy.$$
Can you continue? You might want to consider using the area of a unit circle (or alternatively, polar coordinates).

Comment: @Hamsa Mohamed The assumption that the volume of the slice of the sphere you attached in your picture is the probability is not correct. Instead, note by the above that
$$P(X^2+Y^2\leq 1)=\frac{1}{4} \iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}~dx~dy.$$
Geometrically, what does the last integral represent?

Comment: @projectilemotion I see. what is A? is that the area where $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ is true? do you get this when you integrate $$ \frac{1}{4}\left [  xy\right ]_{X^2+Y^2\leq 1}$$. I think Im lost

Comment: @Hamsa Mohamed In my first comment, $A$ is any region of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So for your problem, you would want to let
$$A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq 1\},$$
which is indeed the area such that $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ is true. Now to evaluate the integral, you can either notice that the integral represents a specific geometric quantity (what does integrating $1$ over a region of $\mathbb{R}^2$ give you?), or you can use polar coordinates (if you have studied multivariable calculus):
$$\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1} dx~dy=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 r~dr~d\theta.$$

Comment: @projectilemotion  integrating 1 of region of $\mathbb{R}^2$? A wild guess maybe a cylinder with height $\frac{1}{4}$ that has an area of unit circle

Comment: Indeed, you are right! The quantity $P(X^2+Y^2\leq 1)=\frac{1}{4} \iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}~dx~dy$ represents the volume of a cylinder of height $1/4$ with unit radius. In general, note that if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then one has
$$\int_A 1~dx=\operatorname{length}(A),$$
Analogously, if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, then one has
$$\iint_A 1~dx~dy=\operatorname{area}(A),$$
Lastly, if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, then one has
$$\iiint_A 1~dx~dy~dz=\operatorname{volume}(A).$$
So what probability do you obtain?

Comment: @projectilemotion Thank you very much. You are awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief simulation in R provides useful graphs and an approximate answer.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = runif(10^5, -1,1)
y = runif(10^5, -1,1)
w = x^2 + y^2
mean(w < 1)
[1] 0.78491     # aprx P(W < 1)
pi/4
[1] 0.7853982   # exact
```

The left panel below illistrates the uniform distribution of $(X,Y)$ in the square of area $4$ with vertices at $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1).$ Orange points correspond to $P(W < 1).$

The right panel shows a histogram of 100,000 simulated values
of $W.$ The desired probability $P(W < 1)$ is the area of the
histogram to the left of the vertical orange line.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))  # enables two panels per plot
 plot(x, y, pch=".")
  points(x[w < 1],y[w < 1], col="orange")
 hist(w, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  abline(v=1, col="orange", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Can you find the density function of $W?.$

Comment: thanks buddy. You just answers the question to my next assignment. Where we have to approx $\pi$ with R using `runif `and this fact $x^2 + y^2 < 1$.

Comment: Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1):

Since X and Y are uniformly distributed, the probability of $X^2+Y^2<1$ is the ratio of the area of the circle to the area of the square, i.e., $\pi/4$. Following a Monte-Carlo approach, you may give an estimate for $\pi$, something like:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/estimating-value-pi-using-monte-carlo/